# What is the composition of the universe's population of neutrinos?

Tags: cosmology, sun, neutrinos

I believe earth-based detectors measure mainly solar neutrinos, which have energies on the MeV scale of nuclear physics, are directed from the sun, and have flavors determined by the sun's nuclear reactions plus neutrino oscillations. In addition to this, I recently learned from a physics.SE answer that the universe  contains neutrinos that are thermalized with respect to the 3 K background temperature of the universe. I assume these latter can't be detected with present technology...?

What is our best present knowledge of the universe's population of neutrinos? Energy spectrum? Flavors? Directions of motion? (Are they isotropic?) Spatial distribution? Are there antineutrinos in the mix? Is the neutrino contribution to the cosmological stress-energy tensor primarily from one component of this population?

Comment: I think we don't know, but i wait till an expert confirm this.

Comment: @Héctor: I'm thinking that the answer would probably involve a combination of empirical knowledge and theoretical predictions.

Comment: I'm not well versed in this field, but [this arxiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0506164) seems to indicate that there's at least 3 flavors.

Comment: @Ben I mean, we couldn't even measure their velocity until a few years ago, and the detection of solar neutrinos is quite recently too. It'll be a major surprise that the energy spectrum, direction of motion or contribution to the stress energy tensor are known facts right now. But i could be wrong of course, i'll wait until an expert see this question.

Comment: @KyleKanos: From the title of the paper, sounds like "relic" is used to refer to the old, thermalized component...?

Comment: @BenCrowell: It seems it's about the population of $\nu$'s that existed after decoupling (which is something like 1s after the big bang), it's at least a part of the population of $\nu$'s (i.e., it's some of the picture, but not all of it).

Comment: @KyleKanos: In this context, does decoupling basically mean when the temperature got below the electroweak unification energy?

Comment: @BenCrowell: I believe that is the case.

Comment: Should be roughly as isotropic as the CMB. Beyond that I am guessing, but I suppose them to be well mixed in flavor and about even in matter and anti-matter type. Mind you, at that energy a modest boost could change the matterness of Majorana neutrinos.

Comment: @dmckee: Wouldn't the low-energy component be gravitationally bound to various objects?

Comment: @BenCrowell Depends a bit on the mass, but I think they are moderately relativistic. Hmm ... I always overlook the pure size of gravitational potentials on the cosmic scale. Yeah, some are almost certainly gravitationally bound at the supper cluster scale even if not at smaller scales. And there goes the nice, simple situation that was set up by inflation.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm too ignorant about particle physics to understand the part about "matterness of Majorana neutrinos." Maybe a topic for another question...?

Comment: @ben Majorana neutrinos have their matter/antimatter state linked to their helicity. Boost to a state where they change helicity and your $\nu$ suddenly looks like a $\bar{\nu}$. Or vice versa.

Comment: @BenCrowell: A paper was posted on arXiv titled, [*Detecting the Diffuse Supernova Neutrino Background with LENA*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2240) seems to be timely & relevant (haven't yet read it though it seems promising to answer the question of detectors)

Answer (score 1):

In many standard theories, Neutrinos are assumed as the be most common particle in the Universe (known as cosmic neutrino background (CNB) a relic of the Big Bang). Many experiments are being carried out to detect them from different sources. Those from the CNB  have been only indirectly detected, but many, originated in violent event across the universe have been detected (for instance, previous to the 1987a supernova explosion a peak of high energy neutrinos were detected (they escaped from the explosion before the electromagnetic radiation could). Giving you a full list of the details you are asking will have to wait to an expert's answer

Answer (score 0):

Background neutrinos can't be detected, but neutrino observatories have detected neutrinos into the high TeV range. See e.g. Icecube http://icecube.wisc.edu/ for a high energy neutrino observatory.